# Cannot check for updates in Excel for Mac 2016

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-word

I'm trying to updates Excel for Mac 2016 and Word for Mac 2016. Apparently when I go to help I should be able to see a 'Check for updates' menu option. However, I cannot see this menu option - see screenshot. how do I update Excel for Mac 2016 and Word for Mac 2016?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see **Check for Updates** on the **Help** menu on Office for Mac, download the latest version of the **Microsoft AutoUpdate** tool from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3133674. Run the tool and then restart Word and Excel. Confirm if the **Check for Updates** option appears on the Help menu.